# What is the difference in Javascript between 'undefined' and 'not defined'?

Tags: javascript

If you attempt to use a variable that does not exist and has not been declared, javascript will throw an error. `var name is not defined`, and the script will stop then and there.

But if you check it using `typeof noname` then it will return `"undefined"`. I always thought that you had to declare a var for it to have a type. Either by using: var a; so it has the type of undefined or by giving it a value like: `var b =5;` so it has the type of its value.

Also what is the difference between `var a;` and `var b = undefined;`?

Answer (score 27):

An undeclared variable (that is, one that doesn't exist) does not have a type - and so its type *is* undefined.  I believe that the generally accepted way to test if something is undefined is

```
typeof var === 'undefined'
```

rather than

```
var === undefined
```

since if the variable does not exist, you cannot access it.  The latter case might be more useful if you are sure the variable *should* exist, since the difference between the two is that an undeclared variable will return false in the first case but cause an error in the second case.

Make sure that you use the triple-equals operator though if you're using the second variant; the (more usual) double-equals operator performs type coercion, so `null == undefined` is true while `null === undefined` is false.  Sometimes you might want the first behaviour, though often you'll want the second, especially if you're testing against undefined, so it's important to recognise the difference.  (This is another benefit of the first case since it's not possible to make this subtle error).

Yes, variables can have a value of undefined and you can explicitly assign values to them.  Assigning `undefined` to a variable though is probably confusing, since it's a bit of a paradox (you've defined the variable as undefined) and it's not possible to distinguish that variable from either variables that don't exist or uninitialised variables.  Use null if you want to signify that a variable has no value currently, or if you want to "undeclare" the variable altogether, use `delete {varname}`.  Assigning undefined to a variable does not remove that variable's declaration; and it will still appear in the list of its owning object's properties if you iterate over them, so I can't think of any situation this would benefit you.

Edit: In response to the comment, when comparing the values with === (or ==), the variable must be deferenced to obtain its current value in order to do the comparison.  Since the variable doesn't exist, this dereferencing fails (no real surprises so far).  While you might expect the typeof operator to work in a similar way (get the current value, see what its type is) it specifically works with undefined variables.  The "short version" (as used by the [Mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/typeof_Operator) ) is simply that "The typeof operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand."

The long version, extracted from the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/E262-3.pdf), is that there's a special case for undefined variables:

> 11.4.3 typeof *UnaryExpression* is evaluated as follows:
>
> 1. Evaluate *UnaryExpression* (as per 10.1.4 this returns "a value of type Reference whose base object is *null* and whose property name is the identifier" if the variable is undeclared).
> 2. If Type(Result(1)) is not Reference, go to step 4.  (It is a Reference)
> 3. If GetBase(Result(1)) is *null*, return "undefined".  (This is the special case matching undefined variables)

As for your comment to the first question, "how can you classify what does not exist" - it's easy!  Simply divide all concepts into things that do exist (e.g. squirrel, rock) and those that don't exist (unicorns, warp drives).  That's what undefined means; regardless of its semantics in English, its Javascript meaning is that the variable hasn't been declared or populated yet, and so while the *concept* of "a variable called foo" is valid, there exists no variable with that name holding a real value.

Comment: Question why doesn't typeof noname choke like var === undefined?
Am i not accessing the var then?

also made an interesting comment above to the previous post, but I think it's relent to this one too.

Thankyou

Comment: "an undeclared variable will return false in the first case" not in my console at least.

Answer (score 18):

JavaScript provides several different notions of missing or empty variables (and object properties):

1. Variables that are actually 'not defined', i.e. they don't exists as a given name isn't bound in the current lexical environment. Accessing such a variable will throw an error, but using `typeof` won't and will return `'undefined'`. In contrast, accessing non-existing properties will not throw an error and return `undefined` instead (and you may use the `in` operator or the `hasOwnProperty()` method to check if properties actually do exist).
2. Existing variables which have not been assigned a value (which is common because of [var hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)) or which have been explicitly set to `undefined`. Accessing such a variable will return `undefined`, `typeof` will return `'undefined'`.
3. Existing variables which have been explicitly set to `null`. Accessing such a variable will return `null`, `typeof` will return `'object'`. Note that this is misleading: `null` is not an object, but a primitive value of type *Null* (which has the consequence that you can't return `null` from constructor functions - you have to throw an error instead to denote failure).

I'd recommend the following practices:

1. Use `typeof` to check for `undefined`, as it will cover the first two cases.
2. Don't assign `undefined` to *properties*: Use `delete` to get rid of them instead; note that you cannot delete *variables* (but also note that globals are actually properties of the global object and thus can be deleted).
3. Use `null` to mark the absence of a meaningful value (eg the forward reference of the last node of a linked list) or if you want to clear a variable as a hint to the garbage collector.

You could go with `undefined` for 3. as well and never use `null` at all.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it's a difference between JavaScript definition and firebugs of the same thing.

Undefined is just the state of something that has not been defined as a value. So it has no type.

> Also what is the difference between var a; and var b = undefined;

```
var a; alert(a); // undefined
a; alert(a); // "Error "a" not defined"
a = undefined; alert(a); // undefined
```

2nd example is not valid JavaScript code and the execution will stop. Since this is an error.

Comment: I thought that undefined it's self was also a type? i.e a primitive type. 

According to the dictionary one of the definitions of undefined is: "to give form or meaning to", To me undefined is like saying it has not meaning. But if it does not exist in the first place then how can it have no meaning. How can you classify what does not exist? 

Thank you for the help and anyone else.

Answer (score 4):

```js
alert(a);
```

Here `a` is not defined.

```js
alert(a);
var a=10;
```

Here `a` is undefined because `javascript` engine convert this code to

```
var a;
alert(a); // that's why `a` is defined here 
a=10;
```

Answer (score 4):

- not defined - instance is not declared and used;
- undefined - instance declared and used without it value.

Answer (score 2):

> **undefined**: Declared but the value not asigned above where we access it
>   in othe word it exist but the value not asigned
>
> '**not defined**': It is an error which indicate to the coder/programmer/user the variable doesn't exist in the scope. Not declare in scope.

```
var a = 1;
console.log(a) //1

var b;
console.log(b) //undefined

console.log(c) //undefined
var c=2;

console.log(d) //undefined
var d;

e=3
console.log(e) //3
var e;

console.log(f) //Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

> ```
> > Note: the default behavior of javaScript moving declarations to the
> > top
> >So the above code is look like below internally
> ```

```
var a = 1, b, c, d, e;
console.log(a) //1

console.log(b) //undefined

console.log(c) //undefined
c=2;

console.log(d) //undefined

e=3
console.log(e) //3

console.log(f) //Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not defined:**

Variable is not declared or initialized. Throws reference error

Example:

```
console.log(newvariable); // results: ReferenceError: newvariable is not defined
```

**Undefined:**

A variable declared without a value will have the value undefined.

Example:

```
var newVar;
console.log(newVar); // results: undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

An undeclared variable does not exist in Javascript memory whereas a declared one does and can be set to undefined.

The difference is caused by Javascript design confusion. If a variable's value is undefined then it should be deleted. Indeed falsy values like 0, "", null, and undefined, are all basically meaningless and identical. A lot of time is wasted on them. They are all nothing and non existent. It is highly contradictory to have more than one type of nothing, or maybe to allow even one.

Therefore I think you should avoid explicitly using falsy values when programming altogether. I didn't find a case yet when they couldn't be eliminated by a better method, and programming is much nicer without them.