# Query about OR operator while inititating a variable

Tags: javascript, initialization

Lets assume modulex and moduley both are not declared at all.
Now consider two scenarios:

`var modulex = modulesx || {};` // This line of code works fine

`moduley = moduley || {};` // but this code throws error saying moduley is undefined.

Again,
`var modulex = moduley || {};` // This also throws error saying moduley is undefined.

Please elaborate on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, variable declarations are [hoisted](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting). This code:

```
var a = a || {};
```

Is actually interpreted like this:

```
var a;
a = a || {};
```

In your second example, `moduley` just isn't defined, which is exactly what your error says.

Comment: Then var a = a || {} doesnt make any sense.. because it would be as good as saying var a= {} ; Also even if a is undefined it should have been interpreted as false and should have taken the value after || operator... Isn't it?

Comment: @AbhijeetPawar: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833661/what-is-the-difference-in-javascript-between-undefined-and-not-defined

Comment: Adding more to question... if I "declare" the same variable twice then the second declaration will have no effect at all... am I right?

Comment: @AbhijeetPawar: Try it out. It doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use variable which was not declared on the left side of "=" or as function parameter. Reference is not initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 'moduley' was not defined before using it, javascript compiler will call it as 'undefined'