# "not defined" error when instantiating object

Tags: javascript

If I create an object like this:

```
var foo = foo || {};
```

There's no problem.

But this:

```
var foo = bar || {};
```

Produces the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: bar is not defined
```

Why doesn't the second snippet work when the first does?

Comment: Well, what is `bar`? You aren't declaring it. The latter example makes sense.

Comment: because you haven't defined bar?

Comment: @CaseyFalk I thought the point of the `variable || {}` syntax was to assign a new empty object if `variable` is undefined?

Comment: **There is a difference between undefined and undeclared.** As soon as you use `var`, `foo` becomes *declared* as `undefined`.

Comment: This reminds me of short-circuiting.

Comment: @Nate undefined is not the same as undeclared.  In your second example bar is never declared so the JS engine doesn't know anything about it.  Oops@Casey Falk beat me to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is a difference between undefined and undeclared.**

As soon as you use `var foo` on the left, `foo` becomes *declared* as [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined). In the latter example, `bar` is undeclared and can't be accessed by the expression on the right.

---

Here are some nifty examples to demonstrate:

```
var foo = (foo===undefined); // foo is now `true`!
var x = x++;                 // x is now `NaN` (the result of `undefined`+1)
var z = v, v = 1;            // z is actually `undefined` here since the "lefts"
                             //   are all declared before the "rights".
```

*Note: You can't do this with globals that don't use `var` (eg: `x=x++`).*

---

Here's a [fun blog post](http://kevinoncode.blogspot.com/2008/12/javascripts-undeclared-versus-undefined.html) about *undeclared* vs *undefined*. And, for more thrills, [here's an SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833661/what-is-the-difference-in-javascript-between-undefined-and-not-defined) that explains how to test whether a variable is declared or not.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't specifically answer why the second doesn't work, I can attempt to answer why the first does work. Through variable hoisting the JavaScript interpretor changes the first one to look like this

```
var foo;
foo = foo || {};
```

so it works and the second doesn't because by the time it runs the second line, foo is declared as undefined.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is the declaration of the variable. If you think about how this is evaluated `var` will be declared for foo before anything else is evaluated. `bar` is essentially pointing to something the namespace is completely unaware of.

Once you declare `var foo` the namespace is aware of the variable regardless of the actual value. In this way without `var` the namespace tries to look for a built in function or some other non variable definition.