# Javascript - condition if variable is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I want to check if a variable is defined before using it, so I wrote something like this

```
if(!variable){
    return null;
}
```

But it throws an error

> ReferenceError: variable is not defined

If I do it like this

```
if(typeof variable === 'undefined'){
    return null;
}
```

It works as expected.

What is the difference between the approaches and why it didn't return null in the first example but instead it died with the error ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference in Javascript between 'undefined' and 'not defined'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833661/what-is-the-difference-in-javascript-between-undefined-and-not-defined)

Comment: You are using variable without defining it. The value of variable is unknown. Javascript not allow us to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When `!variable` is evaluated it tries to get the value of the variable which as [per spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-getvalue) will throw an ReferenceError.

But calling [typeof](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator) will not initially try to get the value of the variable, instead it will check whether the passed expression is a reference, if so then it will check if it is resolvable if nor `undefined` is returned.